# Як правильно "скористУйтесь" чи "скористАйтесь"?

Tags: вибір-слова, дієслова

Звертаюсь за вашою допомогою, знову маю проблеми з правильним написанням такого слова. Адже різні джерела пишуть по різному. 
вжити потрібно у реченні: "Скорист**у**йтесь/Скорист**а**йтесь одним із наведених нижче способів".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Коротко

Наразі **однаково правильно**.

Але коли важлива **лоґіка** чи **скільки раз**, то:

- *скорист**а**йтесь* — один раз;
- *скорист**у**йтесь* — стати користувачем.

---

## Дієіменники

> [Скорист**у**йтесь](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F) — скорист**ува**тися
> [Скорист**а**йтесь](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C) — скорист**а**тися

Обидва дієслова доконаного виду, відріжняються наростком **‑ува‑**.

Спочатку, про всяк випадок, я спробував з простого — поглянути [тлумачення](http://sum.in.ua/) й [переклади](https://r2u.org.ua/). Потім — [правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#diesuf). Очевидно, користі з того було не так багато, цьому значно посприяв вплив [совітизації](http://www.ji.lviv.ua/n35texts/kocherha.htm). Перший висновок: **ріжниця відсутня**. Але, наприклад мені, така відповідь не задовольняє, тому спробуємо розібратися з [історичним] означенням наростка **‑ува‑**.

## Наросток ‑ува‑

[Норми української літературної мови](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky), 1941 · [Олекса Синявський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> #### § 101. Наростки дієслівні: значіння і їх вживання
>
> **1. ‑а‑, ‑я‑**
>
> а) в дієсловах, утворених від іменників: *сідла́ти* (*сідлаю*…), *вінча́ти*, *вече́ряти*, *ка́шляти*…
>
> **в)**  від деяких протяжних форм, зворотні повстають наростком **‑а‑**: *летіти* — *літати* (*літаю*…), *сидіти* — *сідати*, *лишити* — *лишати*, *котити* — качати, *ставити —* ставляти, *тягти* — *тягати*, (*прикрасити*) — *прикрашати*, (*попасти*) — *попасати*, (*дати*) — *давати*, (*умити*) — *умивати*… (між голосними вставний **в**).
>
> ---
>
> **5. ‑ува‑, ‑юва‑** (**‑у‑, ‑ю‑**) — дуже поширений в українських дієсловах наросток з різним значінням:
>
> **а)** в дієсловах недоконаних від іменникових і прикметникових пнів: *дарувати* (*дарую*…), *порядкувати*, *мурувати*, *горювати*…, часто, між іншим, на означення того, хто що робить або чим він є, в якому стані перебуває: *учителювати*, *писарювати*, *гостювати*, *хазяйнувати*, г*осподарювати*, *голодувати*, *секретарювати*, *професорувати*, *козакувати*, *дівувати*, *парубкувати*, *вдовувати*, *кравцювати*, *чабанувати*, *гайдамакувати*, *марнувати*, *пильнувати*, *слабувати*, *радуватися*…, отже іноді ніби рівнобіжне з **‑и‑**: *господарювати* і *господарити*, *гайдамакувати* і *гайдамачити* тощо. Звичайно всі ці дієслова від іменників мають дуже відмінне значіння супроти дієслів основних того ж кореня, напр., *учити* далеко не те, що *учителювати* („бути в учителях, за вчителя“), *косити* не те, що *косарювати* („бути в косарях, за косаря“) і т. ін.
>
> **б)** чималу вагу має цей наросток при творенні наворотних форм дієслів із протяжних: *вихваляти вихвалювати*…, *мордувати замордовувати*, *горювати загорьовувати*…, де, як бачимо, він буває і в подвоєній формі див. [§ 85](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo).
>
> Усі наведені дієслівні наростки органічно звʼязані з творенням дієслівних форм як доконаности супроти недоконаности, наворотности супроти протяжности.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73982/discussion-on-answer-by-follower-----).

Answer (score -2):

Обидва варіанти правильні.

- «Скористайтеся» — наказовий спосіб для «[скориста́тися](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)» (доконане від «користа́тися»).
- «Скористуйтеся» — наказовий спосіб для «[скори́стува́тися](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)» (доконане від «кори́стува́тися»).

У чому я незгоден [із попередньою відповіддю](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3026), так це в тому, що вона стверджує, начебто ці слова мають різницю в значенні (мовляв, «одноразово» і якось інакше).

Насправді за сучасним тлумачним словником («Словник української мови» в 20 томах) у сучасній українській мові [слова «кори́стува́тися» і «користа́тися»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=196526&page=1397) є повними синонімами, просто одне з них має помітку «рідше»:

> **КОРИ́СТУВА́ТИСЯ**, и́сту́юся, и́сту́єшся, *рідше* **КОРИСТА́ТИСЯ**, а́юся, а́єшся, *недок[онане]*.
>   1. *чим і з чого*. Уживати, використовувати що-небудь для власних потреб. <…>
>       // Застосовувати що-небудь. <…>
>   2. *чим і з чого*. Використовувати що-небудь у своїх інтересах, діставати ви́году з чогось. <…>
>   3. *чим*. У сполуч. з абстр. ім. означає: мати що-небудь. <…>
>
> (1) **Кори́стува́тися (користа́тися)** / **скориста́тися (*рідко* скори́стува́тися) по́слугами (по́слугою)**:
>        а) *(кого)* залучати когось до виконання якої-небудь роботи. <…>
>        б) *(чого)* використовувати щось з певною метою. <…>

Тієї є ж думки старіший тлумачний словник («Словник української мови» в 11 томах — він 1970-х років, але, на жаль, новіший на цей момент ще не випустив том на літеру «С») [про слова «скори́стува́тися» і «скориста́тися»](http://sum.in.ua/s/skorystuvatysja) — жодної різниці в значеннях не зазначено, і на цей раз жодне з них не відмічене як «рідковживане».

Можливо, колись різниця в значеннях існувала (або й зараз зберіглася в якихось діалектах), але сучасні словники не відмічають такої різниці.

Так трапляється і з іншими словами, наприклад, «сте́лють» (початкова форма «сла́ти») і «сте́лять» (початкова форма «стели́ти»).

Comment: @Follower, «однаково правильні», але різні за значенням (згідно до Вашої відповіді), чи не так? Якщо не так, то Вам варто переформулювати відповідь. Бо наразі в мене складається враження, що Ваша відповідь стверджує, що саме в сучасній українській мові значення різняться (а не просто згадує етимологію).

Comment: @Follower, «цебто це зовсім не арґумент, чи розуміё пан» — не розумію. Як на мене, всі згадані Вами пари слів у сучасній загальній українській мові синонімічні. Навіть якщо СУМ-20 помиляється, то це поважне джерело, і на їхню позицію варто звертати увагу.

Comment: @Follower, критику читав. Часково згоден, але критика стосувалася, здається, зовсім інших аспектів. І на жаль, при всій недоліках до СУМ-11 і СУМ-20, ми майже не маємо інших тлумачних словників (хіба що ВТССУМ, але він у свій час викликав ще більше критики — і теж не розрізняє значення: [1](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/користатися), [2](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/скористатися)).

Comment: @Follower, ну от і добре, тепер ми з Вами висвітлили обидві позиції: Ви — Олекси Синявського, а я — НАНУ. Якби Ви самі висвітлили у своїй відповіді обидві, то я б не писав свою. (Іще Олекса Синявський загинув в 1937, тому, при всій повазі, його не можна вважати **незаперечним** авторитетом щодо **сучасної** української мови; але і НАНУ теж, мабуть, не можна вважати таким, тому, вважаю, 1:1.)

Comment: @Follower, я думав, що це не взаємовиключні поняття (я думав, що «гинути» означає будь-яку передчасну смерть). «Першиь висновок: ріжницӓ відсутнӓ» — перепрошую, я цього не помітив; мабуть, надто задав тон Ваш вступ «коротко… один раз… стати користувачем». Але з Вашого дозволу, я все-таки поки не буду прибирати свою відповідь, бо Ваша (як мені здається) навіть якщо не логічно, то емоційно надто фокусує увагу на різниці, і я хочу її збалансувати.

Comment: @Follower, незбалансованість Вашої відповіді, на мою думку, виявляється в тому, що: (1) в «коротко» Ви зазначаєте лише одну позицію; (2) загалом два розділи (перший і останній) присвячені позиції про різницю, а середній — радше нейтральний, аніж за відсутність різниці. Тому в читача, що читає Вашу відповідь емоційно, а не логічно, може скластися враження «ну точно є різниця» (а не «є така позиція і є така»). Але можу помилятися.

Comment: @Follower, ну а в мене емоційно при прочитанні складається інше враження. Я припустив, що воно складається не лише в мене. Тому написав свою, щоби компенсувати.

Comment: @Follower, я припустив, що Ви не обов'язково захочете/зможете змінити відповідь у нейтральний тон.

Comment: @Follower, ну давайте так: (1) я маю право написати власну відповідь, хай навіть вона буде замінусованою; (2) якщо Ви зможете змінити Вашу відповідь так, щоб вона здавалась мені нейтральною, або я з якихось інших причин вирішу, що моя відповідь непотрібна — я приберу власну відповідь. Ох і нафлудити ми тут. Добре, я перепрошую, але мені час іти.