# Різниця між словами скористатися/скористуватися?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

[У словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/skorystuvatysja):

> **СКОРИСТУВАТИСЯ**, истуюся, истуєшся і **СКОРИСТАТИСЯ**, аюся, аєшся, чим і з
>   чого. Док. до користуватися, користатися. — *Його зараз же спіймали і
>   наган при ньому знайшли. На моє щастя — не скористувався він ним*
>   (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 169); *Скориставшись телефоном, що стояв
>   біля мене, я за хвилину розмовляв із Станіславом* (Микола Трублаїні,
>   Глиб. шлях, 1948, 44).

Тобто різниці між цими словами немає?

Comment: Largely related: [“Як правильно ‘скористУйтесь’ чи ‘скористАйтесь’?”](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3017/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Як правильно "скористУйтесь" чи "скористАйтесь"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%a3%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%90%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c)

Comment: [Суфікс дієслів **‑ува‑** чи що таке _протяжні_, _наворотні_?](/q/4049/)

Answer (score -1):

Згідно до [Публічного електронного словника української мови](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F), [словника порталу української мови](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F), та, звичайно, СУМу, то різниці між цими словами немає і може вживатися як одне так і інше слово. Також варто навести те, що ці слова позначені як синоніми у [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F).

Comment: Мені здається, що наведені словники не бачать різниці між дією, подією та наслідком, про які йдеться у запитаннях, посилання на які надано у коментарях під цим запитанням. Так, доконану форму дії та події ще важче відрізнити між собою, аніж недоконану форму дії/події, але, як мінімум, ця відповідь не повністю розкриває проблему і може ввести в оману.

Comment: Мені це запитання (на яке Ви відповідаєте) здається дублікатом запитання [«Як правильно „скористУйтесь“ чи „скористАйтесь“?»](/q/3017). Як вважаєте — чи варто позначати це запитання як дублікат і, можливо, вилучати/переносити Вашу відповідь? Я можу зробити це автоматично (перенести відповідь), але цікавить Ваша думка.

Comment: Sasha, гадаю, що питання все ж таки трохи відрізняються, тому думаю, що не варто його позначати як дублікат